# Monkey Patch Chosen jQuery library - Chosen always undefined

Tags: jquery, monkeypatching, jquery-chosen

I am trying to patch two functions within the Chosen jQuery library, however, no matter what I have tried to reference the original functions, console comes back with Chosen is undefined.

Here is my code.

```
        function(){
        var _no_results = window.jQuery.fn.chosen.prototype.no_results;
        var _no_results_clear = window.jQuery.fn.chosen.prototype.no_results_clear;

        window.jQuery.fn.chosen.prototype.no_results = function (terms) {
            console.log('nr');
            var no_results_html;
            no_results_html = $('<li class="no-results">' + this.results_none_found + ' "<span></span>"</li>');
            no_results_html.find("span").first().html(terms);
            if (this.options.no_results_callback) {
                this.options.no_results_callback(no_results_html, terms);
            }
            return this.search_results.append(no_results_html);
            //return _no_results.apply(terms);
        }


        window.jQuery.fn.chosen.prototype.no_results_clear = function (terms) {
            console.log('nrc');
            var no_results_html;
            no_results_html = $('<li class="no-results">' + this.results_none_found + ' "<span></span>"</li>');
            no_results_html.find("span").first().html(terms);
            if (this.options.no_results_clear_callback) {
                this.options.no_results_clear_callback(no_results_html, terms);
            }
            return this.search_results.find(".no-results").remove();
            //return _no_results_clear.apply(terms);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that older versions (e.g. v0.9.14) of the chosen library used to expose `Chosen` and `AbstractChosen`, but neither are exposed in the latest (v1.8.7 as of 2019-03-25).  Instead, the current version takes advantage of the `.data(key, value)` [jQuery method](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to store a reference to the `Chosen` object under the `chosen` key.  You can try using this in conjunction with an initialized chosen select list and the `Object.getPrototypeOf` [JavaScript method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) to override `Chosen` or `AbstractChosen` functions.

For example, suppose somewhere on your page you have:

```html
<select id="futureChosenSelect" ... >
  <option value="HiMom">Hi Mom!</option>
  ...
</select>
```

and you've configured that `<select>` with chosen:

```
$('#futureChosenSelect').chosen();
```

You should be able to override the functions with something like:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf( $('#futureChosenSelect').data('chosen') ).no_results = function(terms) { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy the prototype, that's not how jQuery works. Internaly it stores pluggins and variables in a map (name -> function). This should work:

```
 var _no_results = window.jQuery.jQuery.fn['chosen'].no_results;
 var _no_results_clear = window.jQuery.fn['chosen'].no_results_clear;

 window.jQuery.fn['chosen'].no_results = function (terms) { 
    ...
    _no_results.apply(this, terms);
 }

 window.jQuery.fn['chosen'].no_results_clear = function (terms) { 
    ...
    _no_results_clear.apply(this, terms);
 }
```

I did that once to replace jQuery internal functions for internal log of selector chains. [Check here how it works (github)](https://github.com/fmsf/jQueryLog/blob/master/jquery.log.js#L78)

Comment: unfortunately _no_results still comes back as undefined.

Comment: @ScampDoodle I had added the wrong code initially, I've changed it.

Comment: Just checked the code, you can't access it because they are private variables, that are enclosed in a self running function. You can't change that without directly changing the internal code. At best you can overwrite jQuery.jQuery.fn['chosen'], catch the {no_results_text: "No results matched"} argument, with it run your code and then apply it to the chosen original function